# How to wrap or break long line inside a <span> within a bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap table:

```
   <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-md-12" >   
         <table style="cursor:pointer;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <th>header1</th>
             </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <div>
                             <ul>
                                 <li>
                                       <span>text1></span>
                                  </li>
                                 <li>
                                       <span>text3></span>
                                 </li>
                             </ul>
                             <span>some long text that i want to break</span>
                         </div>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the number of span inside ul tag are dynamic and I don't want to wrap them.
I'd like to break the content inside the last span tag to make them wrap at given width, how do I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give span display property of block and set the width like this:

```
.row span {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pF8vd/

Comment: thanks but I actually have multiple spans inside that div, in this case how do I modify the css? please see my updated content

Comment: Umm.. this way that I told you will apply this styling to all your spans in the div